# How to Get Property Names of Object

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
let obj = {
  ArticleNumber: "173224",
  StoreNumber: "40",
  DeliveryDate: "1/30/2017",
  Qty: "110",
  UOM: "C03"
}
```

Now, I want to create an array of only property names, not values. I saw `getProperty()` method but it is not working. I want something like below:

`{"ArticleNumber","StoreNumber","DeliveryDate","Qty","UOM"}` 
in an array.

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
var keyNames = Object.keys(obj);
```

where the return value is

> An array of strings that represent all the enumerable properties of
>   the given object.

You could find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this by using **for loop**.

```
var yourObject = { ArticleNumber: "173224", 
                   StoreNumber: "40", 
                   DeliveryDate: "1/30/2017", 
                   Qty: "110", 
                   UOM: "C03"}
```

create another array for property names

```
var propertyNameArr = [];
```

you can loop through property names in an array like this

```
for(propertyName in yourObject){
   propertyNameArr.push(propertyName);
}
```

Now **propertyNameArr** will have all property name.